# Hard question about analytics

Tags: calculus, analysis

Please help me with this problem. I think it may be Langrange's theorem but I don't know how to solve it.

> Given $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$, $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, $f\in C^2([a,b])$ and $f(a)=f(b)$. $$M=\max_{[a,b]}f''(x)\quad,\quad m=\min_{[a,b]}f''(x).$$
>   If existed $0<h<b-a$ and $f(a+h)=f(b-h)$, prove $$|f'(a)+f'(b)|\leq \frac{M-m}{2}h$$